# Need help smoothing out the transitions in this javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slideshow that is implemented with script.aculo.us with a text overlay, and it is technically working, but I need smoother transitions than I am getting right now.

UPDATE: JSFiddle link below. Hopefully this will get me some responses?

I think this is a CSS problem. The 'next' image is fading in when it is supposed to, but it is happening below the image that is fading out, then it pops up into place. You can watch this happen by shrinking the browser width. Because of the max-height and the responsive layout this causes things to bounce up and down. I feel like the image needs to be position:absolute to fade in in the right place, but every way I've tried to add that just causes the whole slideshow to disappear completely.

The CSS

```
#slideshowContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    max-height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
/*.slideshow {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
} */  /*(this wasn't accomplishing anything, tried it with absolute also)*/
.slideshowImage {  /*relative = broken, absolute = invisible */
    left:0;
    top:0px;
}
.slideshowImage img { /*relative = broken, absolute = invisible */
    width:100%; 
}
.slideshowOverlay { /*this overlay works just fine, only the images are broken */
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:105px;
    bottom:0px;
    background: rgb(51, 51, 51); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, .8);
}
```

This is the js:

```
var i = 0;          
var image_slide = new Array('image-1','image-2','image-3'); //etc...
var NumOfImages = image_slide.length;
var wait = 6000;

function SwapImage(x,y) {       
    $(image_slide[x]).appear({ duration: 2 });
    $(image_slide[y]).fade({duration: 2});
}

function StartSlideShow() {
    play = setInterval('Play()',wait);  
}

function Play() {
    var imageShow, imageHide;

    imageShow = i+1;
    imageHide = i;

    if (imageShow == NumOfImages) {
        SwapImage(0,imageHide); 
        i = 0;                  
    } else {
        SwapImage(imageShow,imageHide);         
        i++;
    }
}
```

This is what the divs look like:

```
<div class="col span_3_of_3" id="slideshowContainer">
    <div id="image-1"  class="slideshow">
        <div class="slideshowImage"><img src="manage/photos/feature42.jpg"  /></div>
        <div class="slideshowOverlay">
            <div class="slideshowTitle">blah blah blah</div>
            <div class="slideshowSubTitle">blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
            <div class="slideshowMore">...<a href="content.php?id=42">MORE</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="image-2"  style="display: none;"  class="slideshow">
        <div class="slideshowImage"><img src="manage/photos/feature41.jpg"  /></div>
        <div class="slideshowOverlay">
            <div class="slideshowTitle">blah blah blah</div>
            <div class="slideshowSubTitle">blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
            <div class="slideshowMore">...<a href="content.php?id=41">MORE</a></div>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on.

What's weird is that the overlay part of the div fades in and out perfectly, it's only the images that are weird. The image fades out to plain white, then the next image pops in too quickly, except on the last image, which works backwards for some reason.

What I want is a simultaneous and smooth fading in and out, no sudden popping and no whitespace in between. And no bouncing up and down in narrower responsive sizes.

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the behavior: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Nx/6/) Shrink the width of the slideshow window to see what is really happening.

Any help smoothing this out would be greatly appreciated. Please keep in mind that there is no jquery on this page and a solution that does not use jquery would be much preferred as I haven't worked with it before and time is a bit short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is that you are fading in a `div` and fading out a `div` at the same time.. but they are both positioned relatively (this means that the one loaded second to the other in the DOM is pushing the other down below your `overflow:hidden;`)

by using `position:absolute;` on your slides and making them the full size of the container they effectively sit one on top of the other

have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Nx/7/

EDIT: based upon suggestion for scaling proportionately i used a little css trick from the guys over at http://fluidsquares.com/ by using `padding-bottom` and `position:absolute` and `height:0`. updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Nx/10/ (note images scale at a ratio of 12:5 when below 400px high :) )

Comment: That seems to work in the fiddle, but when I do that on my site the entire slideshow container disappears. Also in your fiddle, the overlay no longer stays in place at narrower widths. Thoughts?

Comment: that'd be because i changed the `min-height` variable on the container to just `height`.. i will adjust my answer

Comment: @AnonymousMan do you want the slider to always be the same proportion? ie. do you want it so that the height and width scale relative to one another (say at a ratio of 16:9).. unless the height goes above 400px in which case it would max out and just expand width ways?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'm pretty happy with it just dropping to 75px as is.

Comment: note that when switching back to max-height:400 and adding position:absolute to the image, the whole thing vanishes, same as on live site. Super weird...

Comment: images are always 12:5 ratio if that is useful.

Comment: Still breaks the overlay when you shrink the width though :-/

Comment: Yeah, probably a good idea to update to http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Nx/8/ in answer. That one works. Thanks!

Comment: if you click on the 'edited X mins ago' link you should be able to see it, alternatively the part at the bottom of my answer should have a text section that starts 'EDIT' (you may need to refresh the page).. still.. glad i could help :)

Comment: Now all the content below the slideshow has jumped up and is covering it. :p will try to figure out what to do about that on my own.

Comment: argh, does it do that for you on the jsfiddle? thats all ive got to work from im afraid (i changed both css and html, so watch that there isnt old code floating around) :)

Comment: I'd have to add some code to the fiddle, which I'll prbably do anyway to try and figure it out. Will post it here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Nx/12/ basically I need <div id=middleGroup> to  fall back below the slideshow. Also scrambled my footer somehow, still poking at it.

Comment: @AnonymousMan sorry that was my fault.. i put the `height:0` on the outer container and it should have been on the `padding-bottom` element.. updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Nx/13/